# Windows Server Appfabric unable to install

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, installation

When running the product preparations tool I get the following error:

[image]

I have the following errors in the log file:

[image]

Please give any suggestions, i'm using Sharepoint Foundation SP1 and Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that may be caused from corrupted downloaded files, to fix that:

1. Start Run and type regedit
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` folder
3. Delete the `Error_access_disabled_by_policy` file
4. Restart then try to reinstall the prerequisites wizard.